# How to Split HDFS file using Scala

Tags: scala, unix, hdfs

I have one file at **HDFS** location, before loading that file directly into my **Hive** table I want to split that file and then want to load as a part files.
Im writing below code in my **scala** before loading process.

```scala
import sys.process._
var File_name="FileLocation/Filename"
"split -n5  $File_name" !
"hadoop fs -rm  $File_name"!
```

but getting error like.

```scala
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
split: cannot open ‘$File_name’ for reading: No such file or directory.
```

Can someone please guide me how I can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing s

```
s"split -n5  $File_name" !
s"hadoop fs -rm  $File_name" !
```

Comment: Are you sure it still giving the split: cannot open ‘$File_name’ for reading: No such file or directory. It is able to resolve File_name variable on my machine.

Comment: Its taking variable value.but getting same error  cannot open 'path'  for reading : No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

It can be permissions issue, have you tried this?

```sh
$ hdfs dfs -ls <file path>
```

to see permissions, and then

```sh
$ hdfs dfs -chmod xxx <file path>
```

to change permissions over the file

I hope it gives you some clues.

Regards.